# PHP Random Images

Tags: php, image, file, random

I know this has been asked a million times, but I've been searching for 2+ hours and I cannot find the answer that either works, or isn't in pieces of code that takes fragments from large blocks of code, but I cannot go to bed until I fix this. Otherwise I've wasted a huge part of my night that I could've spent on something more productive.

I found ~4 lines of code answers, but they error in Phpstorm and I don't know how to fix it with code that I don't know since it's still new to me..

I'm a beginner, working on my own project, was going great besides these past 2 hours.

**This is what I used to pull images from a folder,** but I do not want all of the images to be added, only one/two. Because of this, It would be best if they were random.

```
<?php
$files = glob("../uploads/*.*");
for($x = 1 ; $x < count($files); $x++){

    $image = $files[$x];
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'"/>'."<br/>";
}
?>
```

How do I modify this code so only 2 ( or a set number ) of images are Randomly added.

Comment: Instead of this you could simply use `array_rand()`

Comment: Consider taking a look into [rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) in the posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = glob("../uploads/*.*");

for($x = 0 ; $x < 2; $x++)
{

    $fileNum=rand(1, count($files));
    $image = $files[$fileNum];

    echo '<img src="'.$image .'"/>'."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: You have no idea how happy this made me (:

I have an error for some reason after I refreshed a few times, but once I refreshed again it went away, i'm assuming it is something with the file type, I'll look into it. Thank you so much and sorry for the spoon feeding